# сброс формы javascript

Tags: javascript, submit

Есть форма `form` с input`action`, `value` которого пустая строка, есть кнопка `add`, по клику которой вызывается скрипт:

```
function act2() {
    //получение формы
    form.action.value='add';
    form.submit();
}
```

Необходимо сбросить значение input на пустое. 
Навигация на ту же страницу - не вариант - вызывает ряд ненужных багов.
Опытным путем был найдет вариант:

```
function act2() {

    //получение формы
    form.action.value='add';
    form.submit();
    setTimeout( function(){form.action.value=''; form.submit();}, 100)

}
```

Однако появилось одно НО. В зависимости от сервера/количества данных в базе/фазы луны варьируется число, которое стоит под таймаутом, необходимое для того, чтобы функции в нем выполнились.

Есть подозрение, что это все происходит из-за разного времени обработки сервером формы после `submit`. Есть какой-то вариант проверить, закончилась ли обработка формы сервером и только после этого вызвать функции, которые под таймаутом?
Или же есть еще какой-то вариант сбросить значение этого `input`?

UPD: Очистка формы должна быть, естественно, после ее первой отправки на сервер с заполненным `action`.

Сервер **Weblogic**
Какой и как "сервлет" отрабатывает - пока нет возможности отследить.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста. Вам надо сбросить `form.action.value` **до** или **после** submit? Какой *backend* используете?

Answer (score 1):

> Необходимо сбросить значение input на пустое.

Вызов `form.submit();` уже отправил данные, что приведёт к переходу на другую страницу. Следовательно, ничего сбрасывать уже смысла нет.

Форма отправлена, осуществлён переход на другую страницу post-запросом. При обновлении по F5 будет нужен такой же post-запрос, о чём и предупреждает браузер. Если нажать Да, то будет повторно послан последний запрос, независимо от того, что ты успеешь сделать с формой после её отправки. Ты пытаешься это покрыть повторной отправкой form.submit() после изменения, но это неправильно.

> Отлично, суть моего вопроса - как избежать повторной отправки, не используя навигацию на ту же страницу, на которой нахожусь, после первого сабмита

Сделать с той страницы, на которую ты попал post'ом переход через get. Этого можно добиться ответом сервера `302 Found` с редиректом на нужную страницу.

Comment: Если бы был переход на другую страницу или форма бы сбросилась - при F5 не выскакивало бы сообщение о повторной отправке формы, и действие по кнопке add не производилось бы повторно

Comment: @Никита, наоборот, именно после отправки оно и выводится.

Comment: Возможно, мы говорим о разных вещах - после отправки формы ничего в браузере не всплывает

Comment: @Никита, форма отправлена, осуществлён переход на другую страницу post-запросом. При обновлении по F5 будет нужен такой же post-запрос, о чём и предупреждает браузер. Если нажать Да, то будет повторно послан последний запрос, независимо от того, что ты успеешь сделать с формой после её отправки. Ты пытаешься это покрыть повторной отправкой `form.submit()` после изменения, но это неправильно.

Comment: Отлично, суть моего вопроса - как избежать повторной отправки, не используя навигацию на ту же страницу, на которой нахожусь, после первого сабмита

Comment: @Никита, ответ дополнен.